# How to replace Do loops by Inner

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I need to replace `Do` loops by something else because it takes forever with big programs. I have been hinted towards `Inner`, but even though I tried, I did not manage to get what I need. Here's a toy example of my actual problem:

Input:

```
u = {{u1a, u1b}, {u2a, u2b}, {u3a, u3b}, {u4a, u4b}};
v = {{v1a, v1b}, {v2a, v2b}, {v3a, v3b}, {v4a, v4b}};
f = {f1, f2, f3, f4};
```

The output I am looking for:

```
d = {{u1a*v1a*f1 + u2a*v2a*f2 + u3a*v3a*f3 +u4a*v4a*f4},
    {u1b*v1b*f1 + u2b*v2b*f2 + u3b*v3b*f3 + u4b*v4b*f4}}
```

It is important not to have any loop constructs; only `Inner`, `Table`, etc. which are generally faster than loops

Comment: Like `f.(u v)`? (No `Inner[]` here, sorry.)

Comment: What do you mean by (u v)? This is the straight-forward wau to do it:

Comment: Do[d[[i]] = Sum[V[[l, i]]*U[[l, i]]*f[[l]], {l, 1, 4, 1}], {i, 1, 2, 
   1}];

Comment: Why not execute that piece of code I gave to see what I mean? (On that note, please look up `Dot[]` in the docs.)

Comment: @J.M. thankyouuuuuuuuuuu!!! :)))) It definitely works! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To settle this question:

You certainly can use `Inner[]` for the task, like so:

```
Inner[Times, f, u v, Plus]
```

but you should know that *Mathematica*, conveniently enough, knows how to do a dot product. The function for doing this is named, appropriately enough, `Dot[]`:

```
Dot[f, u v]
```

but I find that a bit too long to write, so I use a syntax that is a bit more understandable, at least to me:

```
f.(u v)
```

where the parentheses are needed to give (Hadamard) multiplication higher priority than the dot product.

Comment: Why community wiki, if I may ask?

Comment: @Ajasja, I don't want to get reputation for this answer. (I'm choosing to interpret "CW" as "Credit Waived".)

Comment: Yes, I gathered that. But I was wondering why you don't want to get the reputation (or why you care about this). Is this answer to simple? (Personally I think that every useful answer deserves to be upvoted)

Comment: The upvote would be for your expertise in diagnosing the problem, not the quantity of work visible in the answer, like in the [old story](http://gothither.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/knowing-where-to-hit-it.html) of the man with a hammer...

Comment: @Ajasja, if I consider the (not few!) answers I wanted to get reputation for, but don't; versus the (also not few!) answers I really didn't want to get rep for, but did, this seems like a way I'd prefer to proceed. I have nicer answers languishing for lack of even a glance from other people; should I have to beg attention for those? I think not.

Comment: Well, @j-m, I'm in a quandary. Do you have advice: would you recommend I clean up / continue to contribute to your answer? (Would that be rude to do?) I started my answer before yours was posted; it took me a while and when I posted it, you had given a very fine answer. As a CW, I think I may add to your answer things I thought were useful from mine (in the spirit of CW). Should I/can I then delete my answer? (I'm also not sure a comment is the right channel for this question.)

Comment: No need, @zentient. I've upvoted your fine answer, and I think it helps to have OP be aware of other routes, thus reinforcing the richness of *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html), which gets you there:

```
List /@ MapThread[Plus, u v f]
```

But the [infix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Infix.html) notation for the [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dot.html) product is more elegant (as J.M. proposed in the comment above):

```
List /@ (f.(u v))
```

Note that if you're doing a lot of these computations, that `f.(u v)` has a very slight computational edge, which you can test with the [`Timing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Timing.html) command:

```
    List /@ MapThread[Plus, u v f] // Timing
    List /@ (f.(u v)) // Timing
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and those edits @j-m. I'll try to (remember to) adhere to that styling in the future.